# Auto set value of nested attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model location which has many messages. I am trying to let users who are browsing locations to send messages to location owners.

I have location.rb

```
has_many :messages
accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
```

and message.rb

```
belongs_to :location
```

In locations_controller.rb

```
def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:name,
                                       :user_id,
                                       :image,
                                       :latitude,
                                       :longitude,
                                       location_images_attributes: [:id, :location_id, :location_image, :_destroy],
                                       messages_attributes: [:id, :location_id, :from_email, :to_email, :content])
    end
```

Currently i have in my view the following code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @location do |l| %>
    <%= l.simple_fields_for :messages, @location.messages.build do |m| %>
        <%= m.input :content %>
        <%= m.input :to_email, :input_html => {:value => @location.user.email}, as: :hidden %>
    <% end %>
    <%= l.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I don't want to set the value of the email field via hidden field, but i want to pass value from controller. Or a model. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this approach in your `Location` model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, after_add: :set_email
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages

  def set_email(message)
    message.to_email = user.email
  end
end
```

Basically you have to register a method for `Location`, when new message is added to `messages` set.

In this example I named it `set_email`, which takes the `message` object as it's argument, and you can freely modify it. I'm just setting the `to_email` based on `location`'s `email`.

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks. After some thinking, i realised, that message has location_id. And location has user_id, so i can extract users email via @message.location.user.email...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in the Message model:

```
before_create :set_to_email

def set_to_email
  self.to_email = self.location.user.email
end
```

Downside is that on every create action a few additional database lookups are being performed. So on the grand scale this is not an ideal solution in terms of performance optimization.